# Is it possible to save Tensorboad session?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

I'm using Tensorboard and would like to save and send my report (email outside my organization), without losing interactive abilities. I've tried to save it as a complete html but that didn't work.
Anyone encountered the same issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [`tensorboard.dev`](https://tensorboard.dev/)?

This page allows you to host your tensorboard experiment & share it with others using a link (it's still interactive) for free.

Also you can use it from the command line; try this from your CLI for more information:

```
$ tensorboard dev --help
```

Comment: I think the legal department in my organization wont like it :)

Comment: @Mercury I don't think there is another way except running tensorboard locally (or spinning up your own server with authentication).